# Angular @Optional directive injection is ignored

Tags: angular

I receive a such error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for ControlErrorsDirective: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
```

There is a declaration of the service.

```
    constructor(
        @Optional() @Host() private form: FormSubmitDirective,
        private control: NgControl,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        @Inject(FORM_ERRORS) private errors,
        @Optional() controlErrorContainer: ControlErrorContainerDirective
      ) {
```

I see that the injection problem is related to optional directive services. Yes the directives are not set in to the component. But they are optional. Why is the error invoked?
Yes, I provided all directives to the module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ControlErrorsDirective,
    ControlErrorContainerDirective,
    FormSubmitDirective,
    ControlErrorComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ControlErrorComponent
  ],
```

But it does not work. The error seems trivial. But I do no see it.
Here it works well. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-terms-and-conditions-reactive-forms?embed=1&file=src/app/form-errors.ts
Regards.

Comment: How can we reproduce your issue? If it works in stackblitz then maybe you didn't put something important there?

Comment: I agree with you. I 've checked almost everything. In the internet, somewhere I saw the bug related. The compiler ignored @Optinal decorator. I see I am doing wrong. But I can not define a problem.

Comment: Having `?` in DI error can indicate circular dependency issue. The problem here is that Angular can't recognize FormSubmitDirective and ControlErrorContainerDirective types

Comment: Quick check is to put `console.log(FormSubmitDirective)` in front of your component and see the log

Comment: @yurzui  Sorry. I do not see your idea. Every component has own object locator. I know that the service is not provided because the directive has not been set. But we use the directive ```@Optional``` that has to suppress the error.

Comment: Which error will you get if remove @Optional decorator? This kind of errors should have nothing to do with Optional decorator

Comment: There is not a circular dependency issue. Because these services have not bee provided at all.

Comment: I meant circular dependency between your classes not circular dependency in DI

Comment: Here's an example of such kind of errors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr7fmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdir.directive.ts As you can see I can easely  reproduce this error in stackblitz. Maybe you can share some github repo with minimal code where it can be reproduced?

Comment: I see your idea. But I do not have a such case. There is not a circular injection. There is the full listening of the code https://gist.github.com/vlikin/b7e098d378d3af74c84f40c6f18884a6 The same workable is on the blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-terms-and-conditions-reactive-forms?embed=1&file=src/app/form-errors.ts

Comment: Do you run it in Angular CLI?

Comment: If you have exactly the same file `form-control-error.ts` you added to gist then of course it won't work because the order of your classes matters. You should put `FormSubmitDirective` and `ControlErrorContainerDirective` before `ControlErrorsDirective`  class. It's not circular dependency but leads to the same behavior when type is undefined at the time when it's passed to DI

Comment: Yes the problem was a trivial one as you had described. I corrected the order of classes it works. Yes, the decorators are applied during class definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of errors like:

> Can't resolve all parameters for Something : (?,

usually means that the type used for parameter in constructor is undefined at the time decorator is being executed.

There are several reasons it can happen:

- You have circular dependency between your classes used in DI
- You have all classes in one file and tries to use type before it's declared. So order matters.

In your case you wrote all classes in one file but tries to use `FormSubmitDirective` and `ControlErrorContainerDirective` before `ControlErrorsDirective` class which is the main cause of your issue.